# How to fix "await is only valid in async function" error when using Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, angular, nodemailer

I am trying to create a Contact Us form using Nodemailer by following along a tutorial. The tutorial pastes some code from the Nodemailer website, but the source code has been updated since that tutorial was recorded.

I paste the latest code from the website, but I get the following console error:

> let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
>
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Below is my app.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs());
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

// Static folder
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact");
});

app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
        <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
        <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>    
    `;
    
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
               user: 'youremail@address.com',
               pass: 'yourpassword'
           }
       });

       const mailOptions = {
        from: 'sender@email.com', // sender address
        to: 'to@email.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Subject of your email', // Subject line
        html: '<p>Your html here</p>'// plain text body
      };

      let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server started..."));
```

And the code I'm pasting in is located on this page: https://nodemailer.com/about/

Why am I getting this error, and what changes do I need to make so that the code works as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)` is a async operations and hence the example is using an `await` keyword before it to make the execution synchronous.

However, await keyword is only allowed within method marked as `async`. So in your case you need mark `createTransport` method as async.

For example: 
`async nodemail.createTransport`  another option is to retunr the `transport.sendMail()` from the method and resolve the promise.

For example:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
               user: 'youremail@address.com',
               pass: 'yourpassword'
           }
       });

       const mailOptions = {
        from: 'sender@email.com', // sender address
        to: 'to@email.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Subject of your email', // Subject line
        html: '<p>Your html here</p>'// plain text body
      };

      return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)

});

transport.then(
result =>   {
  console.log("Message sent: %s", result.info.messageId);
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(result.info));
}
);
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because `await` is only valid inside `async` function. Syntax is

```
async function some() {
  await other
}
```

Change this line:

`app.post("/send", (req, res) => {`

to

Note `async` keyword here
`app.post("/send", async (req, res) => {`

Read more about [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use await without making function async. So, Just put async before `(req, res)` like below.

```
app.post("/send", async (req, res) => {
     //other stuff will goes here.
     let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`await` can only be used in an `async` function.

To be noted `async` function is only used to make promises  work in a more comfortable way.

so just add `async` like this`app.post("/send", async (req, res) =>` or remove `let info = await`  from

```
`let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
```

and instead use a `then` chain like this

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then((info) => { your code})
```